# Error Handling on API Call with FetchJsonP / Redux / React

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-observable

Hey I am trying to figure out a way to handle error and api call inside an redux epic, I have checked at this doc:
https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/ErrorHandling.html
I don't have any error, but nothing happens the code seems looping

```
/**
 * Request the JSON guide to the API
 * and then dispatch requestGuideFulfilled & requestGameTask actions
 *
 * @param action$
 */
export function requestGuide(action$) {
  return action$.ofType(REQUEST_GUIDE)
    .mergeMap(({id}) => fetchJsonp(`${API_URL}/guide/${id}/jsonp`)
      .catch(error => requestGuideFailed(error))
    )
    .mergeMap(response => response.json())
    .mergeMap(json => requestGuideFulfilled(json))
    .map(json => requestGameTask(json))
}


export function manageRequestGuideError(action$) {
  return action$.ofType(REQUEST_GUIDE_FAILED)
    .subscribe(({error}) => {
      console.log('Error',error)
    })
}
```

Any Idea ? Thank you !

[UPDATE]: I have an error even on the fetching:

> You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can
>   provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues, so I'll try and elaborate as best I can. To be frank, RxJS is *not easy*. I would encourage you to spend some solid time learning the fundamentals before using redux-observable, unless of course you're just experimenting in your free time for fun and you like pain lol.

It's also critical to not bring in things like redux-observable unless you *really* need complex side effect management. Somewhat unfortunately, the docs currently only have simple examples, but redux-observable is really intended to make complex stuff like multiplex websockets, elaborate time-based sequencing, etc much easier at the expense of needing to know RxJS really well. So I guess I'm saying is, if you do need redux, make sure you need redux-observable too or could get away with redux-thunk. It might seem funny that one of the makers of redux-observable sorta talks people out of using it, but I just see a crazy number of people using things like redux-observable/redux-saga for things that simply don't justify the complexity they bring. *You* know your needs best though, so don't take this as doctrine or be unreasonably discouraged <3

None of the code in this answer has been tested, so it may need minor corrections.

---

> You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

This error is likely caused by `.mergeMap(json => requestGuideFulfilled(json))`. It looks like `requestGuideFulfilled` is an action creator, but the source isn't included here so I can't be sure. `mergeMap` aka `flatMap` expects you to return another stream (usually an Observable), so an action POJO would need to be wrapped in an Observable, like `Observable.of(requestGuideFulfilled(json))` but in this case using `mergeMap` is unnecessary. It could have just been a regular `map()`.

---

```
export function manageRequestGuideError(action$) {
  return action$.ofType(REQUEST_GUIDE_FAILED)
    .subscribe(({error}) => {
      console.log('Error',error)
    })
}
```

In redux-observable all Epics **must** return an Observable. This Epic is returning a subscription observable (the return value of `subscribe()`). This actually does produce an error, however due to a [bug in RxJS it's been silently swallowed](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2813).

Instead you can use `do` and `ignoreElements` to create an Observable that listens for that action, logs that property out, then ignores it (never emitting anything itself). So it's "read only" basically.

```
export function manageRequestGuideError(action$) {
  return action$.ofType(REQUEST_GUIDE_FAILED)
    .do(({error}) => {
      console.log('Error',error)
    })
    .ignoreElements();
}
```

---

The next and biggest issue is where you've placed your `catch`. It's important to learn about how using RxJS means we are chaining Observables together--"operators" basically take a source and return another Observable which will lazily apply some operation on data piped through them. This is very similar to functional programming with Arrays (e.g. `arr.map().filter()`) with two major differences: Observables are lazy and they have a time-dimension.

### How operators work

So consider this Observable chain:

```
Observable.of(1, 2, 3)
  .map(num => num.toString())
  .filter(str => str !== '2');
  .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

- We create an Observable that, when subscribed to, will synchronously emit 1, then 2, then 3.
- We apply the `map` operator to that source which creates a new Observable that, when subscribed to, will itself subscribe to source we applied it to: our Observable of 1, 2, 3.
- We then apply the `filter` operator`to the Observable returned by`map`. As you might have guessed,`filter`returns a new Observable that, when subscribed to, will itself subscribe to the source we applied it to: our Observable of strings we mapped. Because that`map` Observable itself was applied to a source, it too will then subscribe to its source, pulling in the first number and kicking off the map -> filter operation.

It may be helpful to store those intermediate Observables as variables, to demystify things a bit.

```
const source1: Observable<number> = Observable.of(1, 2, 3);
const source2: Observable<string> = source1.map(num => num.toString());
const result: Observable<string> = source2.filter(str => str !== '2');
```

### Inner Observables

When we use operators like `mergeMap`, `switchMap`, `concatMap`, we are saying we want to map each value to another "inner" Observable who's values will be either merged, switched to, or queued (concat) after the previous inner Observable. These have different important differences, but there's lots of resources on them if you're unfamiliar.

In your case we're using `mergeMap`, which also has an alias of `flatMap`, which is the more widely known term used in functional programming. `mergeMap` will provide each value to your projection function and concurrently subscribe to the Observable you return for each. The values of each of those inner Observables are *merged* together.

In functional programming they more often call this flattening, instead of merging. So it may again be helpful to first consider this merging/flattening in the context of Arrays

#### Array.prototype.map

```
[1, 3, 5].map(value =>  {
  return [value, value + 1];
});
// [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]     Array<Array<number>>
```

This resulted in an array of arrays of numbers `Array<Array<number>>`, but what if we instead wanted a single, flattened array? Enter `flatMap`.

#### Array.prototype.flatMap ([stage 2 TC39 proposal](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-flatMap/))

```
[1, 3, 5].flatMap(value =>  {
  return [value, value + 1];
});
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]           Array<number>
```

JavaScript arrays do yet officially have `flatMap`, but it's a [stage 2 TC39 proposal](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-flatMap/) as of this writing. It follows the same semantics as the typical `flatMap`: for each item in the array map it to another array provided by your projection function, then flatten each of those into a single new array.

With Observables, it's pretty much the same except again they are lazy and have a time dimension:

```
Observable.of(1, 3, 5).map(value =>  {
  return Observable.of(value, value + 1);
});
// Observable.of(1, 2)..Observable.of(3, 4)..Observable.of(5, 6)  | Observable<Observable<number>>
```

We mapped each number into their own Observable of two numbers. So a higher-order Observable `Observable<Observable<number>>` and probably not what we wanted in most cases.

```
Observable.of(1, 3, 5).flatMap(value =>  {
  return Observable.of(value, value + 1);
});
// 1..2..3..4..5..6                                               | Observable<number>
```

Now we just have a stream of all the numbers. Perfect!

### Error Handling

Putting together our understanding of operating chaining and Observable flattening, we come to error handling. Hopefully that primer makes this next part easier to grok.

If an error is thrown in any one of our chained Observables it will propagate through the chain in the same fashion as values do, but in its own "channel" basically. So we if we have an Observable chain `a -> b -> c` and an error occurs in `a`, it will be sent to `b` then `c`. When each Observable receives the error it can either handle it in some way, or choose to pass it along to whatever is subscribing to it. When it does, that subscription terminates and no longer listens for future messages from its source.

Most operators just pass along errors (while terminating), so if you aren't using a special error handling operator like `catch` the error propagates until it reaches your observer--the one you yourself passed to `.subscribe(next, error, complete)`. If you provided that error handler, it's called, if not, it's rethrown as a normal JavaScript exception.

To *finally* get to your code, let's start with the end; what I think you actually want:

```
function getGuide(id) {
  const promise = fetchJsonp(`${API_URL}/guide/${id}/jsonp`)
    .then(res => res.json());
  return Observable.from(promise);
}

export function requestGuide(action$) {
  return action$.ofType(REQUEST_GUIDE)
    .mergeMap(({id}) => 
        getGuide(id)
          .mergeMap(json => Observable.of(
            requestGuideFulfilled(json),
            requestGameTask(json)
          ))
          .catch(error => Observable.of(
            requestGuideFailed(error)
          ))
    )
}
```

Now let's break it down.

#### Promise vs. Observable

First thing you'll see is that I abstracted out your `fetchJsonp` into the `getGuide` function. You could just as well put this code inside the epic, but having it separate will make it easier for you to mock it if you decide to test.

As quickly as possible I wrap that Promise in an Observable. Mostly because if we're choosing to use RxJS we should go all-in, especially to prevent confusion later. e.g. both Promise and Observable instances have `catch` methods so it's easy to cause bugs if you start mixing the two.

Ideally we'd use Observables instead of Promises entirely, as Promises cannot be cancelled (so you cannot cancel the actual AJAX request + JSON parsing itself), although if you wrap it in an Observable and unsubscribe before the promise resolves, the Observable will correctly just ignore what the promise later resolves or rejects.

#### Emitting multiple actions?

It's not 100% clear, but it appeared you intended to emit two actions in response to successfully getting back the JSON. Your previous code actually maps the JSON to the `requestGuideFulfilled()` action, but then the next operator maps that action to `requestGameTask()` (which doesn't receive the JSON, it receives the `requestGuideFulfilled()` action). Remember above, about how operators are chains of Observables, the values flow through them.

To solve this, we need to think think "in streams". Our `getGuide()` Observable will emit a single value, the JSON. Given that single (1) value we want to map it to more than one other values, in this case two actions. So we want to transform one-to-many. We need to use one of `mergeMap`, `switchMap`, or `concatMap` then. In this case, since our `getGuide()` will never emit more than one item all three of these operators will have the same result, but it's critical to understand them cause it often *does matter* so keep that in mind! Let's just use `mergeMap` in this case.

```
.mergeMap(json => Observable.of(
  requestGuideFulfilled(json),
  requestGameTask(json)
))
```

`Observable.of` supports an arbitrary number of arguments, and will emit each of them sequentially.

#### catching errors

Because our Observable chains are...well..chains hehe the values are piped between them. As we learned above, because of this *where* you place error handling in these chains is important. This is actually not very different between error handling with traditional exceptions, or even promises, but Promises do not have "operators", so people don't usually run into this confusion.

The `catch` operator is the most common, and it's pretty similar to the `catch` Promises have except **you must return an Observable of the value you want, not the value itself**. `Observable.of` is common here since most often we just want to emit one or more items sequentially.

```
.catch(error => Observable.of(
  requestGuideFailed(error)
))
```

Whenever a error is emitted by the source we apply this operator to, it will catch it and instead emit `requestGuideFailed(error)` and then `complete()`.

Because it emits an action on error, any operators we apply to the result of this `.catch()` **could also be operating on the value our `catch` emits.

```
getJsonSomehow()
  .catch(error => Observable.of(
    someErrorAction(error)
  ))
  .map(json => {
    // might be the JSON, but also might be the
    // someErrorAction() action!
    return someSuccessAction();
  })
```

Although not unique to redux-observable (since redux-observable is mostly just a tiny library and a convention, using RxJS) you'll often see Epics follow a similar pattern.

- Listens for an particular action
- Then merges or switches that action into an inner Observable that performs a side effect
- When that side effects is successful we `map` it to an success action
- In case it errors we place a `catch` inside our `mergeMap`/`switchMap` but most often at the end of the inner chain, so that any actions we emit aren't transformed on accident.

You'll hopefully recognize that general pattern from the redux-observable docs:

```
function exampleEpic(action$) {
  return action$.ofType(EXAMPLE)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      getExample(action.id)
        .map(resp => exampleSuccess(resp))
        .catch(resp => Observable.of(
          exampleFailure(resp)
        ))
    );
}
```

Applying that knowledge to our previous work:

```
getGuide(id)
  .mergeMap(json => Observable.of(
    requestGuideFulfilled(json),
    requestGameTask(json)
  ))
  .catch(error => Observable.of(
    requestGuideFailed(error)
  ))
```

And that's about it, I think.

---

PHEW! Sorry that was so long-winded. It's entirely possible you knew some or all of this, so forgive me if I'm preaching the choir! I started writing something short, but kept adding clarification, after clarification. lol.

If you're struggling, definitely make sure using RxJS and redux-observable (or any complex middleware) is a neccesary complexity for your app.

Comment: **Thank you very much** for this very clear answer !!!!! That's work very well ! It must have taken you a lot of time, but it's very appreciated !